# What are some feasible ideas for building a smart-device/console development portfolio?

Tags: android, ios, linux, embedded-systems, video

I would like to start getting more contracts in the mobile, smart-device, and console development space and, having little prior work experience in the field, I need to build a portfolio of example projects.

Most of my professional experience is based on the .NET stack, so that is helpful in covering Windows Phone, Windows Metro, and  XBOX (non-game) development such as Kinect UI development, media applications, etc.  But I also need to demonstrate that I can handle Android development, Linux development (i.e. Smart TV apps), possibly Arduino development and so forth.

I have the tools and the knowledge to at least knock out some Android and Arduino examples, though iOS and Linux is stretching a bit out of my comfort zone.

In any case, what are some ways in which I could demonstrate that I understand and can code for these platforms?  Media search and filter apps?  Kinect navigation?  Android app that gets you the location of the nearest Starbucks based on GPS coordinates?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can the down-voter please leave a comment so I can improve the question?  If this type of question can't be asked here, then where can it be asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's always good to have a 'look at the puppy' type presentation for mobile stuff.

Why not a simple app that shows off communication?

Chinese whispers, peering from app/os to app/os.... Any fancy throw accelerator craftsmanship the better, and of course make it funny.

Wins over any social media app for me.

Comment: Thanks, Jonno for taking the time to make your suggestion.  I'm not sure I can pull off Chinese Whispers, but using sensors like the accelerometer should demonstrate that I know how to do more than what I would accomplish in any old web-based mobile app.  Thanks again.